# MediaPlayer get max aplitude

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audiotrack

I want to implement a VU meter in my recording app when recording `AND playing`. I know how to do it when recording, but the problem appears when playing. `How can I grab the max amplitude at a given point in time from android MediaPlayer?` I know there is a way because I saw some widget that do the same when playing some music on my device. I don't want to use android Visualizer for rendering, I want to make my own VU meter to work for devices with OS 2.3+. Basically, I need getMaxAmplitude for MediaPlayer.

Answer (score -2):

//first of all import this library

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
                return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
        else
                return 0;

}
```

//if you need further detail here is my class which is doing same thing

```
package com.spaidevelopers.noisealert;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class SoundMeter {
        // This file is used to record voice
        static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

        private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
        private double mEMA = 0.0;

        public void start() {

            if (mRecorder == null) {

                        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 

                        try {
                            mRecorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       mRecorder.start();
                       mEMA = 0.0;
                }
        }

        public void stop() {
                if (mRecorder != null) {
                        mRecorder.stop();       
                        mRecorder.release();
                        mRecorder = null;
                }
        }

        public double getAmplitude() {
                if (mRecorder != null)
                        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
                else
                        return 0;

        }

        public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
                double amp = getAmplitude();
                mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
                return mEMA;
        }
}
```

Comment: OP Is trying to ask how to do this for a MediaPlayer